# How to suppress the deprecation warning "dispatch_get_current_queue() is deprecated...in iOS 6.0"?

Tags: objective-c, ios, deprecated

So the question is the subject question - I want to get rid of this warning which is pretty annoying.

Is there a way to make it silent?

Note: I use dispatch_get_current_queue() for debugging purposes only.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You could use the following code to suppress the warnings.

```
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wdeprecated-declarations"

dispatch_get_current_queue() // your deprecated calling code

#pragma clang diagnostic pop
```