# Suppressing deprecation warning in Objective-C with @available

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch, deprecation-warning

Given the @available command in Objective-C, I was expecting that the deprecation warning would go away just like in Swift. 
Example:

```
ABPerson *abPerson = [participant ABPersonInAddressBook:[ABAddressBook addressBook]];
```

> 'meetingAttendeeWithMeetingPlanner:andABPerson:' is deprecated: first deprecated in macOS 10.11 - use contact framework

With the @available close I can condition the use of the api framework, my guess is that this would silence the warning but it doesn't. Is this the right way to use the @available command, and if it is, is there a way to silence the warning?

```
if (@available(iOS 9, macOS 10.11, *)) {

}
else{
    ABPerson *abPerson = [participant ABPersonInAddressBook:[ABAddressBook addressBook]];
}
```

Comment: You can silence deprecation warnings using a pragma: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14065844/how-to-suppress-the-deprecation-warning-dispatch-get-current-queue-is-depreca/14065939

Comment: Does your @available approach work in Swift? Presumably using #available? AFAIK @available keyword in Objective C doesn't look at `NS_DEPRECATED`, only `NS_AVAILABLE` so this won't work as you have it. Maybe Swift is different.

Comment: @TheNextman, yes I'm using #available works like a charm!

Comment: It is really unfortunate that `@available` doesn't do the expected thing with deprecated functions, and Apple provides no information about what the expected way to conditionally use deprecated functions should be.

Answer (score 3):

```
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wdeprecated-declarations"
... the code using the deprecated API ...
#pragma clang diagnostic pop
```

Answer (score -1):

@available in Objective-C is used when you want to check, if current iOS (/MacOS) version supports this API. It is called when you implement API which is supported starting by some iOS version, but not supported by older iOS.

As far as I know, you can't silent warning about deprecated API - you can only replace it with new.

Comment: "As far as I know, you can't silent warning about deprecated API - you can only replace it with new" < This is wrong, it's trivial to silence the warning in this case using the pragma `-Wdeprecated-declarations`